# Requesting and storing user input c#

Tags: c#, input, console

so this seems kind of silly, but I'm trying to create a program that accepts two x,y,z coordinates from the user and determines the distance between them. However, running this skips lines and gives random numbers. I'm new to c# and would appreciate any help!

```
namespace CoordinateCalcMC
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int X1;
        int Y1;
        int Z1;
        int X2;
        int Y2;
        int Z2;
        int XDist;
        int YDist;
        int ZDist;
        int TotalDist;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the X coordinate of the first point.");
        X1 = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Y coordinate of the first point.");
        Y1 = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Z coordinate of the first point.");
        Z1 = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Your first point is " + X1 + ", " + Y1 + ", " + Z1 + ".");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the X coordinate of the second point.");
        X2 = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Y coordinate of the second point.");
        Y2 = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Z coordinate of the second point.");
        Z2 = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Your second point is " + X2 + ", " + Y2 + ", " + Z2 + ".");
        XDist = Math.Abs(X1 - X2);
        YDist = Math.Abs(Y1 - Y2);
        ZDist = Math.Abs(Z1 - Z2);
        TotalDist = XDist + YDist + ZDist;
        Console.WriteLine("The total X distance is " + XDist + ".");
        Console.WriteLine("The total Y distance is " + YDist + ".");
        Console.WriteLine("The total Z distance is " + ZDist + ".");
        Console.WriteLine("The total number of rails needed to connect these two points is: " + TotalDist);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

[Console.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) reads a single character from the console. As you are assigning the value to an int, you are effectively getting the ASCII value of the character (e.g. if the user entered "1" then the value would be 49, as per asciitable.com).

You need to read in a line of input, and parse the input as an integer, like so:

```
X1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: You mean the first (and perhaps only) [UTF-16](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) code unit (C# [`char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char)) value for the [Unicode codepoint](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). Yes, if the user entered "1", the value would 49. For "", the first value would be 55357 and, in this case, there would be a second value, 57010.

Comment: That makes total sense. I didn't even think about the conversion between. Thanks a lot!